# ApplePay - Unauthorized to process transaction on behalf

Tags: php, applepay

I have two sites running the same php code.  Everything was working in the past.  But one domain stopped working.  I tried reverifying the Merchant Domain.  I also tried removing the Merchant Domain and reverifying again.  I have also triple checked that the crt.pem and key.pem files are the same on both sites, permissions are the same, paths are in the environment, etc.  I also verified that the merchant_id.cer and apple_pay.cer files have the 1BB4Axxxxx as the ID.

But whenever I try to initiate an ApplePay transaction I get an error:

```
Payment Services Exception merchantid=1BB4Axxxxxxxx unauthorized to process transactions on behalf of merchantId=6BF9xxxxxxx reason=6BF9xxxxxx never authorized mass enablement
transactions to occur via 1BB4Axxxxxx",
"statusCode": "400"
```

I have never used "Mass Enablement".  But what also seems weird to me is that the two merchant IDs are different.

On the site that is able to process successfully I see it's using the only the 1BB4Axxx as the ID.